# How to check IF user has ALREADY liked the facebook page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a like button on my website (which is for users to like the fb fan page).

If the user clicks like, I check to see if the even has been fired (event subscribe), and then display some content to them.

**What I would really appreciate help with is the following:**

If the *user is logged in to facebook* AND they already like the page, I want it to display "You're already a fan!" and show the content. (rather than displaying the greyed out like button)

**OR**

If the *user is not logged in to facebook* and they click the like button, I want it to display "You're already a fan!" and show the content. (rather than displaying the greyed out like button)

edit: Guys, I've researched this on SO and have found similar questions but not quite what I'm after. Maybe I'm mistaken but if someone can provide a link to one which describes my exact problem, it would be a lot more helpful than a - on the question. I have checked the following:
[Check if the user is connected to facebook and then check if he liked a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480926/check-if-the-user-is-connected-to-facebook-and-then-check-if-he-liked-a-page)
[Facebook Like Box: How to detect if user already liked the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360058/facebook-like-box-how-to-detect-if-user-already-liked-the-page)
[Facebook LIKE button hiding when page is already LIKED by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163115/facebook-like-button-hiding-when-page-is-already-liked-by-user)
[How to check whether user has liked the page or not using php/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376037/how-to-check-whether-user-has-liked-the-page-or-not-using-php-javascript)
[Check if user already likes fanpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830497/check-if-user-already-likes-fanpage)

Comment: I'm not one of the downvotes, but people might be more inclined to help if you include that comment in your question; link to some questions you've already tried and say why they don't help, so people know you've tried to do it yourself already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score 3):

If you use the facebook php API. i've came up with this short function that u can include inside the base_facebook.php file into the class BaseFacebook.

```
public function userIsFan() {
    $sr = $this->getSignedRequest();
    if($sr && is_array($sr)){
        if(array_key_exists('page', $sr)){
            return $sr['page']['liked'] == 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably better to extend the BaseFacebook class instead of modifying it, otherwise the next time you come to use this function in a different project you'll wonder why it suddenly doesn't work when you grab a fresh copy of the base class. Alternatively if FB change their base class and you upgrade, your custom functions will all get lost (trust me, it happens...)

Comment: This is not working anymore. Signed request no more has information about page liking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using xfbml,
this one works for me

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        FB.api('/me/likes/[page_id]',
          function(response) {
              //console.log(response); - see what the response is on your console.
              if(response.data[0])
                //use script to display your content alert("Liked");
              else
                // just do nothing, display like button alert("Not yet liked");
          }
        );

    });
```

page_id will be the id not the name of your page, to find out the id, just visit `http://graph.facebook.com/[your fb page name]`

hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: This likely requires the `user_likes` extended permission to function.