# FB user: is a fan?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check IF user has ALREADY liked the facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397724/how-to-check-if-user-has-already-liked-the-facebook-page)

If a facebook user is a fan of our page, rather than displaying the "like" button on our website, we want it to show a "thanks" message.

On here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/visible-to-connection/ it seems "visible to connection" is the proper way to do this, however, this is only for fb apps? How can I do this to:

Include a like on the page
IF user is already fan, display other text instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I founded something:
http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/facebook-api-check-if-a-user-is-fan-of-a-facebook-page/20/

I think you need to be logged in to Facebook and you need to know a token as well. Google "facebook graph api" and click first result.

Comment: Thanks Olli! How do I implement something like this "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes/PAGE_ID &access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN" into what I need to achieve. ie: display like button if user is not a fan, otherwise display text? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi! download FB SDK here: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk and then use example provided in url given by me. Search that page for "_So this is how we check using the PHP-SDK:_"