# Facebook: does like?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check IF user has ALREADY liked the facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397724/how-to-check-if-user-has-already-liked-the-facebook-page)

I only have a fan page and I want the like button to be displayed on my website.

http://www.fbrell.com/fb.api/does-like

Following the above example, how could I code up something that works as follows:

User is presented with a like button if they don't already like my page.
User is presented with a "thank you for liking us" text if they already like my page.

I don't have a facebook app, only a page, so I can't really have a grant permissions thing like in the fbrell example.

How can I do this? It's really frustrating because I've tried over and over but cannot get past the bit where I don't have an actual facebook app to do this?

Comment: Please stop posting the same question repeatedly.